# XSLT to convert a specific attribute into element

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XML code:

```
   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
   <ns:getDocumentMessage xmlns:ns="http://ecm.thehartford.com/dms/xsd/2009-06">
  <ecm_cmd_doc xmlns="http://ecm.thehartford.com/ecm_cmd_doc/2009-06" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:schemaLocation="http://ecm.thehartford.com/ecm_cmd_doc/2009-06 ecm_cmd_doc.xsd">  
    <ecm_application_name>gbdedm</ecm_application_name>  
    <ecm_operation mode="synchronous" name="view"/>  
    <ecm_ret_code flag="true" object_id="">/ecm_dev/ecm_dev01/gbd/get/12345678911.pdf</ecm_ret_code>  
    <ecm_ret_code_filename flag="false" object_id=""/> 
   </ecm_cmd_doc>
   </ns:getDocumentMessage>
 </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

which I want to convert into this:

```
    <getDocumentMessage>
    <ecm_cmd_doc>
    <ecm_application_name>gbdedm</ecm_application_name>
    <ecm_operation/>
    <ecm_ret_code>/ecm_dev/ecm_dev01/gbd/get/12345678911.pdf</ecm_ret_code>
    <flag>true</flag>
    <ecm_ret_code_filename/>
    </ecm_cmd_doc>
    </getDocumentMessage>
```

i.e. I want to convert only flag attribute into element. 
I tried this XSLT code:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:ns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" exclude-result-prefixes="soapenv ns">
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@flag">
    <xsl:element name="{name(.)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="soapenv:*">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

But its not working. Flag attribute is not getting converted. 
would appreciate any help on this!

Comment: There are two elements with `flag` attributes in your input, but expected output has only one. Why so?

Comment: yeah, I want only one flag attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the `xmlns:ns` value in your stylesheet is wrong. Second, there is a default namespace in the parent `ecm_cmd_doc` of `ecm_ret_code`. You have to declare that in your stylesheet also. See the stylesheet below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:ns="http://ecm.thehartford.com/dms/xsd/2009-06"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ecm="http://ecm.thehartford.com/ecm_cmd_doc/2009-06"
    exclude-result-prefixes="soapenv ns">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ecm:ecm_ret_code">
        <xsl:element name="{name(.)}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="{name(@flag)}">
            <xsl:value-of select="@flag"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="soapenv:*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```